# Windows Service Fails on Launch

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, .net

I'm trying to write a windows service. It installs fine, but fails when I run it with the following exception.  I've searched for the string "MyNewProgramService", but I can't find any conversions that would throw this error.  I've also added try/catch blocks to a bunch of code with custom exception handling without finding where this exception is occuring.  I'm thinking it's somewhere in the auto-generated configuartion/setup code.  Any ideas?

```
Event Type: Error 
Event Source:   MyNewProgram Event 
Category:   None Event 
ID: 0 
Date:       4/15/2010 
Time:       12:48:34 PM 
User:       N/A 
Computer:   20F7KF1 
Description: Service cannot be started. System.InvalidCastException: 
Conversion from string "MyNewProgramService" to type 'Integer' is not valid. --->
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.    
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value,
     NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)  
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)    
     --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
at TaskManagerFailureHandlerService.MyNewProgramService.OnStart(String[] args)
at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object state)
```

Comment: BTW--I'm working in VB on VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it falls in method `MyNewProgramService.OnStart`, there `Conversions.ToInteger` is called somewhere. Just search for it in method. Then check parameter. It might come from config or something, thats why you don't see string in text.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had a parameter swapped around in a call I was making from the exception handler in the OnStart method.  (One error masking another, what I pain!)  Thanks for getting me onto the right track!

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration file.

You might also check the account the service is running as. Just as a test go to the login tab in the services list and have it login under your own account. If the problem vanishes it's a permissions problem.